# Easy way to replace placeholders in string with the list of values?

Tags: python

I have a long string that contains placeholders, that should be replaced with some data.

```
strOut = "text text {{ }} text text {{ }}"
```

with this pattern

```
pattern = r'\{{(.+?)\}}'
```

It's easy for me to do something like this

```
pattern.sub(self.mymethod, strOut)
```

where mymethod will be called for substitution. It actually works great.
However, this is the problem now. I need to replace all placeholders in string with the values from a list. For example, this is the string again:

```
strOut = "text text {{ }} text {{ }} text"
```

It will always have undetermined number of placeholders. If I also have a list of let's say 2 values

```
myList = [2, 3]
```

I need a way to inject these values into placeholders, and end up with this

```
"text text 2 text 3 text"
```

Number of values in a list and number of placeholder will always be the same, I just don't know in advance how many there will be.

Answer (score 7):

```
my_csv = '%(first)s,%(last)s'
print my_csv % dict(last='Doe', first='John')  # John,Doe
```

I like this for the following reasons :

- the ordering of values is no longer needed
- multiple placeholders can be replaced in one shot.

inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11023271/2147228

Answer (score 3):

Sample code:

```
>>> strOut = "text text {{ }} text text {{ }}"
>>> pattern = r'\{{(.+?)\}}'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(pattern, strOut)
[' ', ' ']
>>> items = iter(str(el) for el in [1, 2])
# as pointed out by @eyquem, this can also be written as:
# items = imap(str, [1, 2])

>>> re.sub(pattern, lambda L: next(items), strOut)
'text text 1 text text 2'
```

This will break if there's not enough parameters to meet the placeholders, but just ignore the remainder otherwise.

And if you're using 2.7+, you're laughing if you can get away with `{}` as a place holder, as you can then just use `'text text {} text text {}'.format(*[1,2])` for instance

**And for "fun"**

(ab)using the lambda, you can do:

```
re.sub(pattern, lambda i, j=(str(el) for el in [1, 2]): next(j), strOut)
```

Comment: @Zed Out of curiousity - any reason you can't use the builtin `str.format` and use `{}` as a placeholder?

Comment: @Jon Clements Isn't ``iter(str(el) for el in [1, 2])`` the fommowing: ``imap(str,[1, 2])`` ?

Comment: @eyquem d0h! Yes it is, I just had iter([1, 2]) and then realised it wouldn't work, so just changed it to a generator

Answer (score 1):

If there are no appearances of `'{}'` (as opposed to `'{{ }}'`) in your `strOut` text, the following approach works.  For `strOut` and `myList` as shown, the string it produces is `'text text 2 text 3 text'`.

```
strOut = "text text {{ }} text {{ }} text"
myList = [2, 3]
strOut.replace('{{ }}','{}').format(*myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [format function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) and pass list with argument unpacking (*)

```
>>> myList = [2, 3]
>>> strOut = 'text text {} text {} text'
>>> print(strOut.format(*myList))
text text 2 text 3 text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (it uses the `count` parameter of `re.sub`):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: strOut = "text text {{ }} text text {{ }}"

In [3]: pattern = r'\{{(.+?)\}}'

In [4]: reduce(lambda x, y: re.sub(pattern, str(y), x, 1), [2, 3], strOut)
Out[4]: 'text text 2 text text 3'
```